# How to debug a scrapy pipeline?

Tags: python, mongodb, debugging, scrapy, pipeline

I am following [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/web-scraping-with-scrapy-and-mongodb/) to learn how to use scrapy and mongodb together. However, I keep getting these error messages:

```
[Anaconda2] C:\Users\Segovia\Dropbox\stack>scrapy crawl stack
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\segovia\anaconda2\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\users\segovia\anaconda2\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Users\Segovia\Anaconda2\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\segovia\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 108, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()
  File "c:\users\segovia\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\project.py", line 60, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "c:\users\segovia\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 285, in setmodule
    self.set(key, getattr(module, key), priority)
  File "c:\users\segovia\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 260, in set
    self.attributes[name].set(value, priority)
  File "c:\users\segovia\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 55, in set
    value = BaseSettings(value, priority=priority)
  File "c:\users\segovia\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.update(values, priority)
  File "c:\users\segovia\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 317, in update
    for name, value in six.iteritems(values):
  File "c:\users\segovia\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 599, in iteritems
    return d.iteritems(**kw)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Can someone tell me what possibly went wrong? Or maybe someone can give me a hint on how to debug it? I've tried the 'parse' method provided on scrapy official documentation but it did not work for me. To debug it, I hope I can use an IDE and 'step-in' these codes and check what is going on in details. Thanks!

The settings.py file has these lines in it:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['stack.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline', ]

MONGODB_SERVER = "localhost"
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
MONGODB_DB = "stackoverflow"
MONGODB_COLLECTION = "questions"
```

And I am sure 'mongod' is running in another cmd window.

Comment: Could you post your project settings as well? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe, I edited the question. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

At this part of your project settings:

> `ITEM_PIPELINES = ['stack.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline', ]`

And at this [documentation page](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#item-pipelines).

Scrapy expects `ITEM_PIPELINES` to be a dictionary and you are giving it a list. Fix it:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'stack.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline': 300}
```

Comment: it worked! Amazing! I really appreciate it! BTW, how did you know the problem is in the settings.py file? I thought it might be in the '__init__.py' file but when I open it, it is empty inside. What does this '__init__.py' do?

Comment: @user3768495 to be honest, I suspected this exact error once I saw the traceback and the `'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`, just because I remembered that long time ago the `ITEM_PIPELINES` was a list, then there was a deprecation warning that it would be a dictionary in the future and now it is a dictionary. I understand that the traceback does not help much in terms of where exactly the error happened, but there are still some clues - see this `settings = get_project_settings()` call - this would tell you that the error happened while reading settings..

Comment: @user3768495 also note that scrapy is open-sourced. You can always look through the code, somewhat follow the traceback on it's [github repo](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy). Hope that helps.

Comment: I see. That's why experience is so important. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: I am kinda new to python, or say programming in general. In a case like this, how can set a 'break-point' and then step into each line of code to inspect what's really going on? I know how to do that in MatLab, but for python I don't.